# Spring boot Jackson date serialization do not include timestamp

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have an application which uses spring boot as backend and angular as frontend. In that application we are sending and receiving dates in some apis between the frontend and backend. The application uses java.util.date. Jackson serializes these dates into ISO format. But if we have a date like '23-11-2020', jackson serializes that into, '22-11-2020T18:30:00+0000'. I am not sure why it is serializes into one day before. Because of that, when the frontend is in a different timezone, it considers the date as 22-11-2020. The backend timezone is IST. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date` as that, unlike the name, actually is both a date and a time. If you want to use date only use `java.time.LocalDate` and forget about the `java.util.Date` and friends.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can i send the date to backend from Angular. Do i need to preprocess it? Because, for some timezones, i am getting previous date in backend. For example, if i am filtering a data by some date, if i enter 23/08/2020, i am getting 22/08/2020 at backend. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: THe problem is not the frontend the problem is the backend representing a date-time.